# Is it possible to convert a class into another class with common attributes?

Tags: oop, class, attributes

Let say I have a class named *CLass1* that has 4 variables inside ( *Object A,Object B, Object C*)
And also I have a class named *Class2* that has 6 variables inside (*Object A, Object B, Object C, Object D, Object E, Object F*)

Is it possible to make an instance of *Class2* using the values from *class1*  and just keep the remaining objects of class2 such as D, E, and F as null?

Comment: Depends on the language, I'd think.

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit class 1 into class 2 and use it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a constructor.
Also, you may set class2 as a sub class of class1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to do, but you can simply create the Class2 by passing it the A, B and C values as parameters on constructor:

```
public Class2 (Object oA, Object oB, Object oC) {
    A = oA;
    B = oB;
    C = oC;
}
```

And in the class 1:

```
public createClass2() {
    Class2 c2 = new Class2(this.A, this.B, this.C);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create methods in class2 like this:

public void demoMethod1(Class1 clazz1)
{
   this.a=clazz1.a;
   this.b=clazz1.b;
   this.c=clazz1.c;
}

or 

public void demoMethod2(Object a, Object b, Object c)
{
   this.a=a;
   this.b=b;
   this.c=c;
}

and you can use it like :
Class2 c2=new Class2();
Class1 c1=new Class1();

c2.demoMethod2(c1.a,c1.b,c1.c);
```